# OSX Swift: Editor placeholder in sourcefile error on NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I keep getting the 'Editor placeholder in sourcefile' error. I am trying to access the text of my NSTextView but I don't seem to be doing it right.

```
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewController(self)
}

@IBAction func saveButtonHandler(sender: AnyObject) {

    let Name: String! = nameField.stringValue;
    let Time: String! = timeField.stringValue;
    let Yum: String! = yumField.stringValue;
    let Instruct = (instructionField.textStorage as NSAttributedString!).string;
    let recipe = Recipe(name: Name, time: Time, yum: Yum, type: foodType, instructions: Instruct)

    dismissViewController(self)
}
```

The problem comes from the line

```
    let Instruct = (instructionField.textStorage as NSAttributedString!).string;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, **if you are using Storyboards or xibs**, you can't have an Outlet to an `NSTextView`. The workaround is to create an Outlet to the target text view's containing `NSScrollView`. So make sure you keep references to `instructionField` as such and it's containing scroll view as such:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView : NSScrollView!

var instructionField : NSTextView {
    get {
        return scrollView.contentView.documentView as! NSTextView
    }
}
```

Next, you do not access the text contained in a text view with `textStorage`. The correct implementation for getting the text contained in `instructionField` is as follows:

```
instructionField.string
```

which is of type `String?`.

---

Now, if you want to get an `NSAttributedString` from `instructionField`, you could do it like so to avoid forcibly unwrapping an optional:

```
guard let str = instructionField.string else { /* else */ }
guard let attrStr = str as? NSAttributedString else { /* else */ }
```

**Finally**

A final fix for your problem line could look something like the following:

```
guard let Instruct = instructionField.string else { /* else */ }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your advice was spot on and I learned a lot from it.

Comment: No problem! @WD